# Translate characters in vim like with tr

Tags: linux, vim, neovim, command-line-tool

I want to translate characters in vim like with the command line tool `tr` or with `sed`:

```
$ echo 'foo bar' | sed 'y/for/tes/'
tee bas
```

So I want to replace all occurrences of certain characters with other characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the content of the buffer through arbitrary external commands with `:help :range!` so you can simply use the tools you are used to:

```
:%!sed 'y/for/tes/'
:%!tr for tes
```

See also `:help !` and `:help !!`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way you can do this with vim out of the box, but the plugin [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) enables something along these lines:

```
:S/{f,o,r}/{t,e,s}/g
```

This will do the same thing as the `sed` command you posted.